# angularfire2 get child reference

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I have a firebase database like this
[image]

How can I get the items for `phase` and `places`? My goal is to write a function `getSelectOptions(key:string)` that returns a list for displaying select options for the supplied key. I would like to reduce database queries to 1 by only getting the `select-options` from firebase and then returning a subset within the function. I have so far:

```
this.selectOptions = af.database.list('/select-options');
```

And the returned selectOptions is
[image]

Comment: Are there any other objects in `select-options` than these 2?

Comment: yes many more this is just for examplification. i guess I do not really know how to use observables

Comment: I think this is not related to observables. (angularfire returns an observable for the data. But, not related). I think it cannot be done in 1 database call. You might have to do 2 databse calls. If possible, redefine your data-model to do this in 1 call.

Comment: But all the date is included in the returned observable already i just have to filter it and put it in a form that angulars `ngFor` can understand

Comment: Ohh. So you do not have any problem in getting all the data in the object `select-options`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround that might help you, but there must be another way to do it:

```
this.selectOptions.subscribe(items=> {
   for(let options of items){
     for (var property in options) {
          if (options.hasOwnProperty(property) && property.indexOf("$")!=0){
            console.log(options[property]); //Should contain an object phase.
          }
     }
   }
});
```